# AttributeError: module 'posts.views' has no attribute 'edit'

Tags: python, django, pycharm, frontend

I am trying to import the views  created from my views.py file to my urls.py file for my django project. After doing so, the terminal displays an attribute error. I am following a tutorial that says it works and I do not know what to do

I've tried everything. I've also checked stack overflow messages. Nothing has helped.

posts/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from .forms import PostForm
from .models import Post
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView


# Create your views here.
class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = 'posts/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'post_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.all()


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/post-detail.html'

    def postview(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = PostForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            return redirect('index')
        form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'posts/post.html', {'form': form})

    def edit(request, pk, template_name='posts/edit.html'):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
        form = PostForm(request.POST or None, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
        return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})

    def delete(request, pk, template_name='posts/confirm_delete,html'):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            post.delete()
            return redirect('index')
        return render(request, template_name, {'object': post})
```

posts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('edit/<int:pk>/', views.edit, name='edit'),
    path('post/', views.postview, name='post'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.delete, name='delete'),
]
```

The website is meant to be up and running with the preloaded posts showing. Instead i am seeing this error message

> File "C:\Users****\PycharmProjects\CRUD\CRUD\posts\urls.py", line 6, in 
>       path('edit//', views.edit, name='edit'),
>   AttributeError: module 'posts.views' has no attribute 'edit'

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is wrong:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/post-detail.html'

def postview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('index')
    form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'posts/post.html', {'form': form})

def edit(request, pk, template_name='posts/edit.html'):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, instance=post)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('index')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})

def delete(request, pk, template_name='posts/confirm_delete,html'):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post.delete()
        return redirect('index')
    return render(request, template_name, {'object': post})
```

Comment: You put the additional 4 spaces for those functions (`postview`, `edit`, `delete`) and so they became a part of `PostDetailView` class. You should move them to the same level of indentation as that class, just the way I did in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

.edit and .postview and .delete are PostDetailView methods you can't access them like that
instead if you want to imeplement those methods with Class Based Views (CBV) you should use other precoded generic views

[CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview)

[UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview)

[DeleteView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview)

so you should implement these 3 CBVs PostCreateView, PostUpdateView, PostDeleteView
and after that your url patterns would be eventually like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('edit/<int:pk>/', views.PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='edit'),
    path('post/', views.PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
]
```

Happy coding!

Comment: That's not the issue here, he's following a tutorial.

Comment: it is a solution to the problem though
and in this situation why using cbv and function based views together?
makes codes messy in my opinion
and he/she accepted the wrong weird answer anyway!